# Android; Drawing + Buttons

Tags: android

It's hard to explain my goal here, so I'll try my best.

Let's say I wanted to draw on the screen, four squares that add up to one big square, like this;

```
 ____ ____
|    |    |
|____|____|
|    |    |
|____|____|
```

Once I get my screen like that, how do I set each one of those four squares into buttons? Thanks guys.

Comment: Create a TableLayout and then in each row you would have 2 columns with a button or an imageview which you can turn into a button

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I would like to be able to have a pinch to zoom in/out function, so TableLayouts are out of the question. Right?

Comment: No it can be done have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085420/how-can-i-enable-pinching-and-stretching-on-my-apps-ui

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for a table layout to help you out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/imageButton1 />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/imageButton2 />
  </TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/imageButton3 />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/imageButton4 />
  </TableRow>
```

You could alternatively populate it with java code

Comment: Well, I'm going to have 117 buttons, in the shape of a periodic table. To answer the un-asked, yes I'm making a periodic table application lol. I already have all 117 element activities with information created, and I know how to call to them, and stuff like that. I'm just wondering if there's and easy way to put, or arrange, 117 buttons on the screen. With that, I would also like a pinch to zoom, and a pan-able screen.

Comment: So you would definitely have to generate your layout using java. I would still go with a table layout seems like the best option for the periodic table. Instead of an ImageView maybe a text view. As for pinch zoom according to the link I posted above seems like it is doable.